# Colorbrewer in D3 & Scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, colors, leaflet

I have a `geoJSON` looking like so

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"crs":{"type":"name",
"properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},
"features":[{"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"scalerank":10,"natscale":1,"labelrank":8,"featurecla":"Admin-1 capital","name":"Colonia del Sacramento","namepar":null,"namealt":null,"diffascii":0,"nameascii":"Colonia del Sacramento","adm0cap":0,"capalt":0,"capin":null,"worldcity":0,"megacity":0,"sov0name":"Uruguay","sov_a3":"URY","adm0name":"Uruguay","adm0_a3":"URY","adm1name":"Colonia","iso_a2":"UY","note":null,"latitude":-34.479999,"longitude":-57.840002,"changed":4,"namediff":1,"diffnote":"Added missing admin-1 capital. Population from GeoNames.","pop_max":21714,"pop_min":21714,"pop_other":0,"rank_max":7,"rank_min":7,"geonameid":3443013,"meganame":null,"ls_name":null,"ls_match":0,"checkme":0},
"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-57.8400024734013,-34.4799990054175]
}}]
}
```

I want to set to use `colorbrewer` to chose colors, depending on the value `pop_max` takes. Then I want to display this point data on a `leaflet map` through overlaying a `svg` ontop of leaflet. I can easily display the points and chose the color like so:

```
var feature = g.selectAll("path")
.data(collection.features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.style("fill", function(d) {
    if(d.properties.pop_max) < 1000 {
        return("red")
    } else if {....
    };
});
```

However, inconvenient.

So i tried:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
.range(colorbrewer.Greens[7])
.domain(0,30000000);

var feature = g.selectAll("path")
.data(collection.features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.style("fill", function(d) {
    colorScale(d.properties.pop_max);
});
```

That does not display any points at all... Note that I estimated my domain. 0 is not necessarily the lowest number nor 30000000 the highest.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to find the max and min `pop_max`, something like this should work:

```
var extent = d3.extent(geojson.features, function(d) { return d.properties.pop_max; });
```

Second, since you want colors to represent 7 ranges of values you should be using [d3.scale.threshold](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#threshold):

```
var N = 7,
    step = (extent[1] - extent[0]) / (N + 1),
    domain = d3.range(extent[0], extent[1] + step, step);
var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain(domain)
    .range(colorbrewer.Greens[N]);
```

**EDITS**

Looks like [quantile](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantile) can do this easier:

```
d3.scale.quantile()
 .domain([extent[0], extent[1]])
 .range(colorbrewer.Greens[N]);
```

Comment: I thought be beauty of the colorbrewer/d3.scale is that it does all of that by itself? I just give it a domain of min and max values, it creates the classes and then colors my data according to the classes?! Why do I need all these calculations? Doesnt work though..

Comment: @Chrissl, you are right, since your ranges are continuous quantize should work for this.  Your mistake above though is that  `domain` should be an **array**.

Comment: it looks like the `3.extent(geojson.features...` function does not return what it is supposed to be. It says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pop_max' of undefined` undefined.

Comment: @Chrissl, trying it with the snippet of geojson in your question, it works for me.

Comment: @Chrissl, if you can create a jsfiddle or plunkr I'll take a look.

Comment: @Mark `.domain([extent[0], extent[1]])` is equivalent to `.domain(extent)`, right?

Comment: @Chrissl, D'oh, Yes, equivalent.   I'm losing it.  I think the blizzard has wrecked my brain.

Comment: @Mark creating a fiddle is hard - i am working with R-Shiny. However, I need to include `colorbrewer` as suggested here at the bottom http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5577023 (linking to the `js` file).